# Azure Backend Cost for a simple app

Tags: android, ios, azure, mobile, azure-mobile-services

I am planning to create a simple app hotel booking app that will be used by 300-500 users per month. Im looking to use Azure mobile services at its backend service. I have no idea how much I will be using

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?scenario=mobile

First come to my mind is I only need
an SQL Database
an Blob Storage
and an API service

Basically im a targeting a minimum viable product so the lower the cost, the better. Does the free account sufficient enought to launch an minimum viable app?

If not can someone estimate for me using

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?scenario=mobile

Comment: You already found the link to the calculator, which is your best resource. Plus you have pricing for everything, at azure.com. Nobody will know your app usage except for you. This is fairly broad & wide open for interpretation (not a good fit at StackOverflow). We don't know how you'll scale, how you'll set yourself up for high availability, what database tier you'll go for... You should be able to broadstroke it yourself, run some load testing, etc. Also: Pricing isn't a programming question.

Comment: And as far as database choice: Only you can make that decision, whether SQL Database service, DocumentDB service, or VM-based database-of-choice. And we have no idea how much data you'll have, so again, that's all up to you to decide how large a database you'd need, how much storage, etc.

Comment: Before this post gets deleted: apply for Bizspark, get up to $750/mo for 3yrs of free Azure credit.  You'll have plenty of runway and room to work with and grow

Comment: We don't recommend the Free tier for an app that is in production. It has daily quota limits, and can be stopped (and restarted) when there is inactivity. The Basic tier might be sufficient for that number of users, depending on what your app is doing.